# Reset my custom SELECT tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

How to reset my custom SELECT tag please ? My code doesn'y works.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/abXAH/2/

```
<select id="choice_moment" name="choice_moment" class="styled">
    <option value="Pas de préférence">No preference</option>
    <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
</select>

<button id="btn-validate" type="submit">Reset</button>

$("#btn-validate").click(function() {
    $('#choice_moment').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

Comment: Your custom select code doesn't seem to refer to the original select element after retrieving the initial values.  Resetting the original select has no bearing on the custom element at that point. If you want to tightly couple the two elements you could manipulate the selected value of the original and have the custom listen for those changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your jsfiddle, you code will probably work. The issue is that you're recreating the select box using javascript.

I've added a line that "resets" your fake select box, but there may be a better way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/abXAH/23/

```
$("#btn-validate").click(function() {
    $('#choice_moment').val('Pas de préférence');
    $('.styledSelect').text('No preference');
});
```

Comment: +1 but, the best would be to learn about Build jquery Plugins. http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html

Comment: Really the best solution would be to remove that custom select code. It seems unnecessary, with a simple div container and CSS they'll be able to achieve exactly what they want without the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something preventing your code to work. With this single line it work

```
  $("#btn-validate").click(function() {    
       $('#choice_moment').val("Pas de préférence");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/abXAH/2/